# Redirect URL with parameters to another URL with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Using htaccess, I want to redirect

```
index.php?page=search&action=go&string=John+Doe
```

to

```
search.php?string=John+Doe
```

but only if page=search and action=go in the first url (string varies)

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please note that SO is _not_ a free coding service! You are expected to attempt yourself and only ask for assistance with your own code when you point out a specific issue you cannot solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below rule,

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=search&action=go&string=(.+?)$
RewriteRule ^ /search.php?string=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: And if the query string comes with additional arguments or a different order of arguments?

Comment: 1. Additional arguments:


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=search&action=go&string=(.+?)&(.+?)$

2. Arguments are the same, but order varies. Apply RewriteCond in sequence:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=search$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=go$
RewriteRule # here comes the rule